# Proving that if $xy + yz + zx \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$, then $x+y+z\geq \sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality

If $x, y, z$ are positive real numbers such that 
$$xy + yz + zx \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$
then prove that $x+y+z\geq \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the contrapositive, we suppose $x+y+z<\sqrt 3$ and want to prove
$$xy+yz+zx<\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\iff (xy+yz+zx)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)<1$$
Scale $(x,y,z)$ by dividing all variables by $\sqrt3$. Then $x+y+z<3$ and we want to prove
$$(xy+yz+zx)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)<27$$

And that's a simple AM-GM:
$$(xy+yz+zx)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\le\left(\frac{2(xy+yz+zx)+x^2+y^2+z^2}3\right)^3=\left(\frac{(x+y+z)^2}3\right)^3<27$$

Comment: i could not understand after the scale(x,y,z) part. Please help @user2345215

Comment: @novak Actually, it isn't really necessary. You can stay with $x+y+z<\sqrt 3$ and then compute $((x+y+z)^2/3)^3<((\sqrt3)^2/3)^3=1$ at the end. I used it as an intermediate step when finding a solution to get rid of the square root of 3.

Comment: Thanks just realized its easy AM-GM

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3 \iff x^2+y^2+z^2 + 2(xy+yz+zx) \geq 3 \iff x^2+y^2+z^2+ \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\geq 3 \iff t^2 + \dfrac{2}{t} \geq 3$. By AM-GM inequality: $t^2+\dfrac{2}{t} =t^2+ \dfrac{1}{t}+\dfrac{1}{t}\geq 3$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my solution is the same as yours, but I assure you I couldn't understand it at all and noticed some similarity only after finishing my proof.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Sketch indicates the truth of the proposition. Blue boxes : $x+y+z > \sqrt{3}$.
Blue with purple centers   $$xy + yz + zx > \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
The surfaces indicate where equality holds.

Comment: ?? What is this supposed to mean

Comment: Don't you like graphs?

Comment: I like graphs, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: Eh... drawing a sketch never hurts.